# Use of the word "own"

Tags: vocabulary

Why do you use own in sentence like this? Isn't it useless? Or it just seems right to you naturally?

> depend on your **own** sense of style
>   depend on your sense of style
>
> your money
>   your **own** money

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that sentence and that phrase mean more or less the same with or without *own*. However, that doe not mean that *own* is useless!

There is a difference in emphasis, and therefore in connotation between your two options.

If I want to tell someone to depend on their style, instead of, say their money, or their education, I could tell them

> Depend on your *style*! (Not on something else!)

If I want to tell them to depend on *their own style* instead of letting their style be dictated by others, I would say:

> Depend on your *own* style! (Not on someone else's!)

In that same way, if I want to tell someone to use their money to get something, instead of stealing it, I could say:

> Use your *money* to buy that! (Don't steal it!)

If I want to emphasize they should use their own money instead of, for instance, getting money from their parents, I'd say:

> Use your *own* money to buy that! (Instead of using someone else's!)

Answer (score 0):

To me, both of those sentences have the exact **same meaning** and **both sound natural**.

It's just another one of countless examples of "optional words" in English.  Usage depends on personal preference and regional differences.

That being said, you may be using ***depend*** incorrectly, but that *depends on* the missing part of these sentence fragments.